# Implementing a method

Tags: java

I have a program I mostly got everything right but I am stuck at one point. This class implements a class which has a `doReading()`; method.

```
 public class MyMath2 extends Homework2 implements Processing {
    int pages;
    public MyMath2() {
        super();
    }
    public void createAssignment(int p) {
        typeHomework = "Math";
        pages = p;
    }

    public void doReading() {

    }
    public String toString() {
        return typeHomework + " - must read " + pages + " pages";
    }
}
```

At this part

```
    public void doReading() {

 }
```

What would i do so that will subtract 2 pages from the pages read at a time.

Comment: @Dukeling I actually didn't know that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This is mine public void doReading() {

    this.pages = 2;  // subtract 2 from the current page count.
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but I'd expect a line like this:

```
public void doReading() {

    this.pages -= 2;  // subtract 2 from the current page count.
}
```

Comment: Oh yes thats correct i did the same thing except i forgot the - sign before the =. Thanks

Comment: @user2255017 alternatively, you can do `this.pages = this.pages - 2`, and `this.pages -= 2` is really not too much more than a shorthand for that.

Comment: @Madbreaks I think that the answer is simple and clear enough that it's impossible for the OP to not learn from it.

Comment: @SamIam: you should see the OP's latest question, and you might change your tune.